# Comparing Two Strings in MIPS

Tags: string, loops, assembly, char, mips

I was trying to compare two strings because of my adding integers code which i [posted here before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36268759/exit-from-adding-integers-loop-with-a-character/36269002#36269002). I could take string from user, also convert that to integer, but i have faced a problem during comparison of string (max size is 20 and if string is less than 20, there will be spaces) read from user and my character " * ". I thought that if i can compare them and they are not equal, i convert to integer and continue to adding, if they are equal it will exit from loop.

I wrote a simple code for comparing two strings, however that didn't give the result. Here is my code;

```
.data
  str1:  .asciiz "Comp"
  str2:  .asciiz "Comp"
.text

main:
  la   $s2, str1
  la   $s3, str2
  move $s6, $s2
  move $s7, $s3
  li   $s1, 5


  beq  $s6, $s7, exit

  move $a0, $s1   
  li   $v0, 1
  syscall


exit:  

  li   $v0, 10      
  syscall
```

After i have checked QtSpim's registers $s6 and $s7, i observed that there are different values. How can i compare two strings? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I've adapted your program to prompt the user for strings, so you can try many values quickly. The `cmploop` is the "meat" of the string compare, so you can just use that if you wish.

Here's it is [please pardon the gratuitous style cleanup]:

```
    .data
prompt:     .asciiz     "Enter string ('.' to end) > "
dot:        .asciiz     "."
eqmsg:      .asciiz     "strings are equal\n"
nemsg:      .asciiz     "strings are not equal\n"

str1:       .space      80
str2:       .space      80

    .text

    .globl  main
main:
    # get first string
    la      $s2,str1
    move    $t2,$s2
    jal     getstr

    # get second string
    la      $s3,str2
    move    $t2,$s3
    jal     getstr

# string compare loop (just like strcmp)
cmploop:
    lb      $t2,($s2)                   # get next char from str1
    lb      $t3,($s3)                   # get next char from str2
    bne     $t2,$t3,cmpne               # are they different? if yes, fly

    beq     $t2,$zero,cmpeq             # at EOS? yes, fly (strings equal)

    addi    $s2,$s2,1                   # point to next char
    addi    $s3,$s3,1                   # point to next char
    j       cmploop

# strings are _not_ equal -- send message
cmpne:
    la      $a0,nemsg
    li      $v0,4
    syscall
    j       main

# strings _are_ equal -- send message
cmpeq:
    la      $a0,eqmsg
    li      $v0,4
    syscall
    j       main

# getstr -- prompt and read string from user
#
# arguments:
#   t2 -- address of string buffer
getstr:
    # prompt the user
    la      $a0,prompt
    li      $v0,4
    syscall

    # read in the string
    move    $a0,$t2
    li      $a1,79
    li      $v0,8
    syscall

    # should we stop?
    la      $a0,dot                     # get address of dot string
    lb      $a0,($a0)                   # get the dot value
    lb      $t2,($t2)                   # get first char of user string
    beq     $t2,$a0,exit                # equal? yes, exit program

    jr      $ra                         # return

# exit program
exit:
    li      $v0,10
    syscall
```

Answer (score 0):

The comparison relates the pointers.  There needs to be a dereferencing in there.

```
lb  $s6, ($s2)
lb  $s7, ($s3)
```

Also, there needs to be checks for end of string.

```
lb  $s6, ($s2)
bz  eos
lb  $s7, ($s3)
bz  eos
```

Comment: Of course you're not suggesting that one compare two strings by comparing the first two characters, but rather that he use a loop to compare all characters one-by-one. He should look at how to implement `strcmp`.

Comment: I did you suggestion but I have taken syntax error in Qtspim.

Answer (score 0):

A simple String Compare compiled using MIPS, prints ASCII difference of first unmatched character it encounters

```
.text
.globl main

main:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, msg1
    syscall

    li $v0, 8
    la $a0, string1
    li $a1, 99
    syscall

    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, msg2
    syscall

    li $v0, 8
    la $a0, string2
    li $a1, 99
    syscall

    lb $t5, endline

    # compare each bit
    la $t1, string1
    la $t2, string2

    loop:
    # load the characters 
        lb $t3, 0($t1)
        lb $t4, 0($t2)
    # check if equal, if not stop loop, if equal, then continue 
        sub $t6, $t3, $t4

        beq $t6, $zero, continueEqual
        j end_loop

    continueEqual:
    # if t3 or t4 == '\n' stop loop
        beq $t3, $t5, end_loop
    # continue again, by incrementing both address by one
        addi $t1, $t1, 1
        addi $t2, $t2, 1
        j loop

    end_loop:

        beq $t6, $zero, same

        notSame:
        li $v0, 4
        la $a0, msg4
        syscall

        j printRes
        
        same:
            li $v0, 4
            la $a0, msg3
            syscall

    printRes:
        li $v0, 1
        move $a0, $t6
        syscall
        li $v0, 4
        la $a0, endline
        syscall

exit:
    li $v0, 10
    syscall


.data

msg1: .asciiz "Enter string-1: "
msg2: .asciiz "Enter string-2: "
msg3: .asciiz "Same\n"
msg4: .asciiz "Not Same\n"
endline: .asciiz "\n"
string1: .space 100
string2: .space 100
```